# Voting buttons doesn't revert back when one cannot change their vote in elections

Tags: bug, voting, user-interface

The upvote/downvote button doesn't turn back to blue (pressed) when a user cannot change their vote:

> [image: demo-image]

Reproduced from [CR elections](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=primary). This bug is probably present in other sites too...